# Else statement of Javascript menu that changes on scroll not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, menu

So I have this menu that changes when you scroll past the first portion of the page (I called it "banner") and in its responsive form it changes to a typical toggle bar where the menu slides down.

```
<header class="ease">
    <div class="menu-toggle"><img src="imgs/vap-designs-logo-black.svg" class="logo" alt="Vap Designs - Logotype" /></div>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="imgs/vap-designs-logo.svg" class="logo" alt="Vap Designs - Logotype" /></a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="menu">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="graphic.html" class="menu">graphic</a></li>
            <li><a href="video.html" class="menu">video</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="menu">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I use Javascript to change its css properties when the user resizes the window. The class 'header-white' changes the background color and height of the header (I prefer to do this instead of just adding the properties via Javascript). The point is that I want my header to have permanently the class 'header-white' when the window is less than 768px wide. It seems to work until the moment you scroll up or down, when it changes even though in the else statement it's not specified to do that.

This is the script:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    h = $('.banner').height();

    if ($(window).width() > 768) {

        $('nav').css({'display' : 'block'});
        $('header').removeClass('toggle-white');

        if ($(document).scrollTop() > h) {
            $('header').addClass('header-white');
            $('header > a img').attr('src', 'imgs/vap-designs-logo-black.svg');
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass('header-white');
            $('header > a img').attr('src', 'imgs/vap-designs-logo.svg');
        }

        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= h ){
                $('header').addClass('header-white');
                $('header > a img').attr('src', 'imgs/vap-designs-logo-black.svg');
            } else {
                $('header').removeClass('header-white');
                $('header > a img').attr('src', 'imgs/vap-designs-logo.svg');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('nav').hide();
        $('header').addClass('header-white');
    }
}).resize();
```

Comment: you have to remove the 'scroll' handler when the window gets smaller, otherwise it is still called when the window is scrolled, regardless of size.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the 'scroll' handler in the else part, otherwise it is still triggered even if the original condition is not met. you can do that like this:

`$(window).off('scroll')`

(or, if you have multiple scroll handlers, save the function in a variable and pass it to both .on and .off )